# Attach multiple files (both dynamic and static) in apps script based mail merge

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to combine the code for mail merge using drafts and the code for auto-filling a google doc with data from google sheet to generate dynamic pdfs. The combined code works as long as I comment out the line

```
attachmentList.push(attach2)
```

How do I combine multiple attachments? What is causing this error?

A snippet of combined code that has an issue:

```
 var attachmentList = [];
        
 var docId = generateLetter(row); // generateLetter is the function to fill google doc template with data from google sheet and this is working properly
    
 var attach1 = {fileName:DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getName(), content:DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(), mimeType:'application/pdf'}; // convert googledoc to pdf attachment is also working
    
 attachmentList.push(attach1);  //this dynamically generated pdf is getting sent in email
                
 var attach2 = {fileName:'Policy.pdf',content: emailTemplate.attachments, mimeType:'application/pdf'}; // this is the inline attachment which by itself is getting sent but not when included in following attachmentList array.
        
 attachmentList.push(attach2); // I get "invalid argument for attachment" error if this line is uncommented
               
 GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,
          attachments: attachmentList, 
//attachments: emailTemplate.attachments works and so does attachmentList.push(attach1) but if attachmentList.push(attach2) is add it gives invalid argument error.
          inlineImages: emailTemplate.inlineImages
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the attachments, not the `json` object:

```
var attachmentList=[DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getAs('application/pdf'),
                   emailTemplate.attachments];
       
GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,
          attachments: attachmentList, 
          inlineImages: emailTemplate.inlineImages
        });
```